# Windows asks for administrator password when starting my application in a non-administrator account

Tags: windows, admin

There is something my application is doing that is causing Windows to ask for an administrator password when starting my application in a non-administrator account.
At first I thought it was because I was writing some data in the run time folder in Program Files. I took care of that but still have the problem.
Do you have any idea how I can track down the problem ?

Comment: Sounds like your program is tagged to run with elevated privilges.

Comment: You must make sure that your program has a manifest, and that the manifest is configured to asInvoker rather than requiresAdmin. If you're using Visual Studio, those options are under Linker -> Manifest File.  If you're starting it via a shortcut, you should also check that the shortcut does not have the "run as administrator" option enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harry Johnston's comment is correct.

If you don't have a manifest that specifies the level, then Windows assumes this is an "old" program written before manifests were common.  In that case, it'll use heuristics to guess whether the program might require administrator privileges.  In particular, if the name of the executable has "install" or "setup" in it, Windows might assume that it's an installer and that it will require administrator privileges.

If you provide a manifest that specifies a level (like asInvoker), then Windows won't guess, regardless of the name of your program.

Comment: Yes. I gave Harry an uptick vote on that comment. It was helpful. I do have a simple manifest but it did not have a requestedPrivileges statement. As a preliminary test, I added the statement, with requestedExecutionLevel set to "asInvoker while still logged on as asministrator. It crashes. Any idea why. (let me know if I should open a new question instead of continuing here.)

Comment: I suspect the crash is for an unrelated problem.